# Microsoft graph - Remove null values from result report

Tags: powershell, graph, graphql, microsoft-graph-api

I'm having issues with Graph filtering out values that are null. The overall goal is an inactive report to report on users who have last logged in 90+ days ago. **Licenses are assigned via group, in** **extensionattribute15**. The script is below:

```
# Azure AD Enterprise App for authentication to the 84 tenant
$AppId = "X"
$TenantId = "X"
$AppSecret = 'X'

# Construct URI and body needed for authentication
$uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"
$body = @{
    client_id     = $AppId
    scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    client_secret = $AppSecret
    grant_type    = "client_credentials" }

# Get OAuth 2.0 Token
$tokenRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $uri -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $body -UseBasicParsing

# Unpack Access Token
$token = ($tokenRequest.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).access_token

# Base URL
$headers = @{Authorization = "Bearer $token"}

# Get User sign in data
Write-Host "Accessing the Graph to get user sign-in data..."
$URI = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?`$filter=startsWith(extension_1fe7973b28e74213b897d62528e614c7_extensionAttribute15,'E') or startswith(extension_1fe7973b28e74213b897d62528e614c7_extensionAttribute15,'f') or startswith(extension_1fe7973b28e74213b897d62528e614c7_extensionAttribute15,'k')&$select=displayName,userPrincipalName, mail, department, jobTitle, extension_1fe7973b28e74213b897d62528e614c7_extensionAttribute14, extension_1fe7973b28e74213b897d62528e614c7_extensionAttribute15, accountEnabled, signInActivity, UserType, id&`$expand=manager(`$select=displayName,userPrincipalName)&`$top=999"
$SignInData = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Headers $Headers -Method Get -ContentType "application/json") 
$Report = [System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]]::new() 


Foreach ($User in $SignInData.Value) {  
   If ($Null -ne $User.SignInActivity)     {
      $LastSignIn = Get-Date($User.SignInActivity.LastSignInDateTime) -format g
      $DaysSinceSignIn = (New-TimeSpan $LastSignIn).Days }
   Else { #No sign in data for this user account
      $LastSignIn = "Never" 
      $DaysSinceSignIn = "N/A" }
## Report headers and variables 
   $ReportLine  = [PSCustomObject] @{
       
     UPN                = $User.UserPrincipalName
     DisplayName        = $User.DisplayName
     Email              = $User.Mail
     SignInStatus       = $User.accountEnabled
     Department         = $User.department
     AADLastSignIn      = $LastSignIn
     JobTitle           = $User.jobTitle
     JobCode            = $User.extension_1fe7973b28e74213b897d62528e614c7_extensionAttribute14
     License            = $User.extension_1fe7973b28e74213b897d62528e614c7_extensionAttribute15
     Manager            = if($User.manager) { $User.manager.userPrincipalName } Else {$null}
}
   $Report.Add($ReportLine) 
}

# Check for additional data to obtain
$NextLink = $SignInData.'@Odata.NextLink'

While ($NextLink -ne $Null) { # If so, proceed with processing the additional data.
   Write-Host "Still processing..."
   $SignInData = Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri $NextLink -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $Headers
   $SignInData = $SignInData | ConvertFrom-JSon
   ForEach ($User in $SignInData.Value) {  

   If ($Null -ne $User.SignInActivity)     {
      $LastSignIn = Get-Date($User.SignInActivity.LastSignInDateTime) -format g
      $DaysSinceSignIn = (New-TimeSpan $LastSignIn).Days }
   Else { #No sign in data for this user account
      $LastSignIn = "Never" 
      $DaysSinceSignIn = "N/A" }
     
   $ReportLine  = [PSCustomObject] @{  
     UPN                = $User.UserPrincipalName
     DisplayName        = $User.DisplayName
     Email              = $User.Mail
     SignInStatus       = $User.accountEnabled  
     Department         = $User.department
     AADLastSignIn      = $LastSignIn
     JobTitle           = $User.jobTitle
     JobCode            = $User.extension_1fe7973b28e74213b897d62528e614c7_extensionAttribute14
     License            = $User.extension_1fe7973b28e74213b897d62528e614c7_extensionAttribute15
     Manager            = if($User.manager) { $User.manager.userPrincipalName } Else {$null}
}
     $Report.Add($ReportLine) } 

   # Check for more data
   $NextLink = $SignInData.'@Odata.NextLink'
}

$Report | Sort DisplayName | Out-GridView
```

The script outputs users who are licensed, but all of the last sign-ins are "Never" and not their actual date. Removing the filter of course results their actual last sign in date, but outputs all non and licensed users.

Does anyone have any suggestions to any edits I can make, or a better way to filter non-values for extension15? I'm unsure if it would be more efficient to possibly filter these values below $Reportline. Any help is much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to detect the inactive users:

[image]

The signInActivity resource type is available only on the Microsoft Graph beta endpoint and isn't yet supported in US Government GCC High environments.

For more information:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/howto-manage-inactive-user-accounts#how-to-detect-inactive-user-accounts

Answer (score 0):

From past experience there were issues everytime I used something like

`If ($Null -ne $User.SignInActivity)`
you are using.

Wouldn't hurt to try something in the lines of

`If -not([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($User.SignInActivity))`

The variable could be an empty string and not a completely $null variable

Hope my guess helps you achieve what you are trying to do